# Allocation of seats to the student(P&C-Probability)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

There are five students $_1, _2, _3, _4$ and $_5$ in a music class and for them there are five seats $_1, _2,_3,_4$ and $_5$ arranged in a row, where initially the seat $_$ is allotted to the student $_$, =1,2,3,4,5. But, on the examination day, the five students are randomly allotted the five seats.

For =1,2,3,4, let $_$ denote the event that the students $_$ and $_{+1}$ do NOT sit adjacent to each other on the day of the examination. Then, find the probability of the event $_1\cap_2\cap_3\cap_4$.

Comment: You could go for finding $1-P(T_1^{\complement}\cup T_2^{\complement}\cup T_3^{\complement}\cup T_4^{\complement})$ by means of inclusion/exclusion but I think brute force would do better here (especially because symmetry lacks). There are not so many possibilities.

Comment: This is small enough that a careful hand count is reasonable, especially if you use the symmetry.  Count the successes when $S_1$ sits in the first seat and there will be the same number when $S_5$ sits there.  There are only $120$ orders and you can eliminate whole chunks of them.

Comment: Samar, you've been around long enough to have a notion that simply copying a problem statement like an assigned exercise does not provide the sort of content that Math.SE seeks to curate.  It will help in future posts if you give some idea of what understanding *you* bring to the problem (what makes the problem interesting? or difficult?).

Answer (score 1):

I'll try again..........I don't see an easy method to determine the number of ways students S1 to S5 do not sit adjacent to a consecutive numbered student, other than counting.

I came up with $13524, 14253, 24153, 24135, 25314, 31425, 31524, 35142, 35241, 41352, 42531, 42513, 52413, 53142$.

This makes a total of $14$ seating arrangements out of $5!$ seating possibilities.
Hence $P(_1\cap_2\cap_3\cap_4) = \frac{14}{5!} = \frac{7}{60}$

The downside of this method is that it is easy to miss a seating combination.....which I did.

Comment: I missed that, I thought it was only for 4 students. The fence post mistake.

Comment: This is correct ,I also got the same answer but I need to solve it by inclusion - exclusion principal

Comment: It's hard to come up with a systematic process whereby you don't double count exclusions. For example, there are 48 ways of excluding 1,2 and 2,1 $(2\cdot 4\cdot 6)$ but when excluding 2,3 or 3,2 you have to not include the already counted 1,2 and 2,1s. combinations.